# How to have recursion, or a hierarchy lists and sublists in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, recursion, windows-store-apps

Say I have the following class, `Employee`

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Underlings { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the following XAML, bound to an `ObservableCollection<Employee> MyEmployees`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyEmployees}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Tag="{Binding Path=Employee.Id}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Name}"></TextBlock>

        <!-- Here's where I declare my underlings -->
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employee.Underlings}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid Tag="{Binding Path=Employee.Id}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Name}"></TextBlock>
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This allows each employee in the collection `MyEmployees` to have some underlings. But *those* underlings are also of type employee, and could have their own underlings. How do I  cater for those additional levels without making my XAML very complex?

Is there some way to declare my `DataTemplate` separately and allow it to be referenced within itself?

Do I have to do all this from code-behind instead?

(I realise the XAML above may not be 100% correct, its just an example)

Comment: Do you want a fully recursive UI or a TreeView?

Comment: Make it a ControlTemplate/Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

therefore you have to use a `TreeView` and not a `ListBox`. And You have to specify a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: I think it can be done in  ListBox, just not a good idea probably.

Comment: Why not a good idea? How is a treeview better? Seems like I have to go install a toolkit just to use a Treeview as there's no native one in WinRT

Answer (score 0):

You could define the DataTemplate inside the ListBoxes Resources as the default template for Employees:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyEmployees}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myns:Employee}">
            <Grid Tag="{Binding Id}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Underlings}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: There's no DataType in WinRT apparently, so that won't work either